# Concat two strings in an update query to update column

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, concatenation

I want to update a column by joining two strings together, but postgresql (version 10) gives me an error that it's not possible.

This is the results from the select query:

```
select game_id, distro, kernel, de, os_bit, 'ubuntu ' || (regexp_matches(distro, '(x|k)ubuntu ((16|18|17)(\.04|10)(\.\d)).+'))[2] from games 
where distro ~ 'ubuntu (16|18|17)(\.04|10)(\.\d)' and distro !~  '^ubuntu (16|18|17)(\.04|10)(\.\d)$'
```

[image]

I want to update the distro column, and it should contain the string that in the picture is displayed under the `?column?` column, but when I use the following query, an error (set-returning functions are not allowed in UPDATE) occurs:

```
update games set distro = concat('ubuntu ', (regexp_matches(distro, '(x|k)ubuntu ((16|18|17)(\.04|10)(\.\d)).+'))[2]) where distro ~ 'ubuntu (16|18|17)(\.04|10)(\.\d)' and distro !~  '^ubuntu (16|18|17)(\.04|10)(\.\d)$'
```

Comment: Using a test table on my side, it works fine for me with PG 9.3: `UPDATE my_table SET field = CONCAT('xx', (regexp_matches(field, '(\d)(\S)'))[2])`

Comment: @eurotrash could this maybe be changed in version 10, which I am using? Because the error keeps popping up and I need to update the columns with static strings

Comment: Right you are, tried with 10 and got that error. Do this instead: `concat('ubuntu ', (SELECT (regexp_matches(distro, '(x|k)ubuntu ((16|18|17)(\.04|10)(\.\d)).+'))[2]))`, that will get around that error.